# Transpose and split a record using awk

Tags: awk

I've record like this

```
35366302,Shenzhen Basicom H838
35180800,Adcon Telemetry A733 addWAVE GSM
35347200 35557601,ACT''L eWON
45005801 45006201 45006202,AEG 9020/AEG HT901
```

And i want to get the result like this.

```
35366302,Shenzhen Basicom H838
35180800,Adcon Telemetry A733 addWAVE GSM
35347200,ACT''L eWON
35557601,ACT''L eWON
45005801,AEG 9020/AEG HT901
45006201,AEG 9020/AEG HT901
45006202,AEG 9020/AEG HT901
```

How to use a proper awk command for this case ?

a complete records is such like below.

```
45006401 45006402 45006405 45006501 45006502 45006701 45006702 45006705 45006801 45006802 45006805,39,AEG HT911,aLQn5h,-9,aeg_ht911,N,N/A,N/A,No,No,N,Proprietary,Proprietary,N/A,N/A,GSM 900,N,Y,N,N,U,U,No,U,N,N,N,N,0,N,0,N,N,N,N,No,-9,-9,-9,-9,N/A,Basic Phone,N/A,N/A,-9,-9,-9,-9,N/A,N,N/A,N,N,N/A,N/A,N,N,No,0,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N/A,-9,-9,-9,-9,U,-9,N/A,N/A,U,U,U,U,U,U,U,N/A,N,U,N,N,N,Y,N,N,N,N,N,U,N,N,N,N,U,U,-9,N,N,U,N,N,N,N,N,N,1,1,0,0,-9,-9,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,-9,-9,N/A,N/A,-9,-9,N/A,N/A,0,N/A,-9,-9,N,N/A,U,-9,0,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,-9,N/A,-9,0,No,N/A,-9,N/A,-9,No,-9,No,N/A,0,N/A,N/A,-9,-9,N/A,0,N/A,N/A,-9,-9,N/A,-9,N/A,N/A,No,-9,N/A,-9,N/A,N/A,N,-9,-9,N/A,0,0,N/A,N/A,N/A,U,0,-9,N/A,N/A,No,N/A,0,-9,No,0,N/A,N/A,N/A,0,-9,N/A,No,N/A,N/A,N/A,-9,N/A,U,U,N/A,-9,N,N,N,N,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another `awk` :

```
awk -F, '{split($1, a, " "); for(i=1; i<=length(a); i++){$1=a[i]; print}}' OFS=, file
```

Comment: FWIW `i<=length(a)` could be just `i in a` and then it would even work on older awks that don't allow `length(array)`.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NR>2 {i=0; j=split($1, a, " "); while(i<j){print a[++i]","$NF}} NR<=2{print}' File
```

**Output:**

```
35366302,Shenzhen Basicom H838
35180800,Adcon Telemetry A733 addWAVE GSM
35347200,ACT''L eWON
35557601,ACT''L eWON
45005801,AEG 9020/AEG HT901
45006201,AEG 9020/AEG HT901
45006202,AEG 9020/AEG HT901
```

Comment: Hi @A.M.D i try with yours awk, it seems doesnt work and not get all the rest of columns, please see on the top that a complete records.

Comment: this was not present in the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r ':a;s/([0-9]{8}) ([^,]+)(,.*$)/\1\3\n\2\3/;ta' file
35366302,Shenzhen Basicom H838
35180800,Adcon Telemetry A733 addWAVE GSM
35347200,ACT''L eWON
35557601,ACT''L eWON
45005801,AEG 9020/AEG HT901
45006201,AEG 9020/AEG HT901
45006202,AEG 9020/AEG HT901
```